# Using promise in Vue, How do i get data from API?

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, async-await, promise

In my repository.js i have the following:

```
async getAllContactRequests() {
    return new Promise(() => {
      axios
        .get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/contactRequests", {
          headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("user_token") }
        })
    })
  }
```

In my Vue component i have:

```
<script>
import repository from "@/api/repository";

export default {
  name: "posts-index",

  data() {
    return {
      apiData: null,
    };
  },

  async mounted() {
    console.log("This prints");
    this.apiData  = await repository.getAllContactRequests().then(result => result.data);
    console.log("This doesn't print");
  },
};
</script>
```

I don't get the data from the promise, and every line after the call to the api function does not execute. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The promise is never resolved. Do not return a new Promise, just return `axios.get` because it's a Promise already. You don't even need the `async` at all in that specific case (in the repository)

Comment: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: An additional note. When using `await` you in most cases don't need `then`. `this.apiData  = await repository.getAllContactRequests().then(result => result.data);` can be written as `this.apiData  = (await repository.getAllContactRequests()).data;`

Comment: AWESOMe! So far so good. Now, how do i actually access the data? The object is Promise, can i convert it to JSON somehow? or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the API returns JSON data, you can refactor the codes above into:

```js
async getAllContactRequests() {
    return axios
        .get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/contactRequests", {
          headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("user_token") }
        })
  }
```

This is because Axios returns Promise, and there is no need to redundantly wrap it into a Promise.

To consume the response data, you simply await for the API request:

```js
import repository from "@/api/repository";

export default {
  name: "posts-index",

  data() {
    return {
      apiData: null,
    };
  },

  async mounted() {
    const response = await repository.getAllContactRequests()
    if (response && response.data) {
       this.apiData = response.data
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: Should the getAllConectRequests() method have the async keyword if you aren't using await in the body of the function?